# armv7s in third party framework

Tags: ios, armv7

Im building a third party framework with the help of this link:
https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

I encountered a problem upon building for armv7s architecture.
    ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice

I found a solution to this problem in:
[Compile Library for armv7s - cputype (12) and cpusubtype (11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549489/compile-library-for-armv7s-cputype-12-and-cpusubtype-11)

But the solution does not seems to work for my case.
I have add the code changes to [build_framework.sh] script at the last 2nd command.
I replace [lipo] to [xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo].
The build was successfully. But when i add the framework to another project. It gives the same problem.

any ideas?

Comment: Check project->target->Build Setting->Compiler forC/C++/Objective-C set value Default Compiler.

Comment: it is set to default compiler already.